# Python>How to pass CSV Headers & values under headers, as API req parameter/payload, dynamically (without hardcoding headers in code) with request lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, csv, python-requests

I am creating utility which will pull API definition and associated request parameter from database. Then pushing that information to CSV (this is requirement). Till this part I am done. Now CSV I have look like this:
[image]

(Apologies for adding csv image.. this editor won't allow me to add same data in default table format)

Now, I want to pass these headers and respective values from column as api request parameters.
If, API does not have values configured then we can ignore and pass empty body.

```
Ex1: 
http://localhost:8080/cm/apis/API6%2Ftoday?username=MyTestUser70
  { "paramsR": {
        "M1": "70878-008",
        "C1": "467345-121",
        "T1":"Hi 2"
    }
}
```

```
Ex2:
http://localhost:8080/cm/apis/API3%2Ftoday?username=MyTestUser70
  { }
```

What I am trying for this looks like this:

```
with open('apis.csv') as csv_file1:
    csv_apis_read = csv.DictReader(csv_file1)
    fields = csv_apis_read.fieldnames
    api_csv = list(csv_apis_read)
    for apis in api_csv: 
        #print(fields)
        #print(apis .get('M1'))
        #apis.get('S1')
        #apis.get('C1')
        final_url = f"{http://localhost:8080}{urllib.parse.quote_plus(apis.get('APIDef'))}"
        #req_json = {"paramsR": {"S1" : apis.get('S1')}}
        req_json = {"paramsR": {"M1" : apis.get('M1')}}
        username = {"username": "MyTestUser70"}
        headers = {'Accept': "application/json",'Content-Type': "application/json",'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",'Cache-Control': "no-cache",'Token': "null"}
        response = requests.request("POST", f_url, json=req_json, headers=headers, params=uid)
        print(response.request.url)
        print(response.request.body)
        print(response.request.headers)
        print(response.text)
```

Q1.*How can I pass header value as payload & associated column value as request parameter for all available APIs one by one dynamically (without hardcoding header values in code.)? 

**Note**: Header values are not fixed. After re-generating csv mentioned at first step headers and associated values updates. That's why I am looking to generate this key-pair combination in dynamic way instead of hard-coding and pre-defining anything with header and column values.* 
Q2.*While passing request parameters is there any way to remove [''] from M1 and T1 column values?*

Can someone please guide me with this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pandas` library's iterrows function,

```
import pandas

api_file = pandas.read_csv("apis.csv")

for index, row in api_file.iterrows():
    row = dict(row.dropna())
    
    api_url = row['APIDef'] # Add the prefix
    row.pop('APIDef')
    
    for key in row.keys():
        if key == "M1":
            row[key] = eval(row[key])[0]
        if key == "C1":
            row[key] = int(row[key])
        if key == "T1":
            row[key] = eval(row[key])[0]
        if key == "S1":
            if row[key]:
                row[key] = True
            else:
                row[key] = False
    
    req_json = {}
    
    if row:
        req_json["paramsR"] = row
    
    print(api_url, req_json)

    
    # Make your requests
```

Output that prints out the endpoint followed by the params.
[image: API_endpoints, Params]

Happy Coding!

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7762470/dhivakar-chelladurai Thanks for the suggestion. But here again we are hardcoding keys (column headers) which I want to avoid basically. Building body param & its value dynamically from csv is my basic intension.

Comment: I think adding type()==int|str|list checks to row values will fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7762470/dhivakar-chelladurai could you please update the actual code from answer with reference to your comment "type()==int|str|list" ?